# JavaScript reference in TypeScript file

Tags: javascript, soap, typescript, soap-client

I have a JavaScript file from:
http://javascriptsoapclient.codeplex.com/

I need to write my program in TypeScript.

My problem is now that I don't know how to integrate this .js file in my .ts file.

I want to use `SOAPClient` from the .js file to invoke methods from the Service.

Some code from the .js:

```
function SOAPClient() {}

SOAPClient.invoke = function(url, method, parameters, async, callback)
{
    if(async)
        SOAPClient._loadWsdl(url, method, parameters, async, callback);
    else
        return SOAPClient._loadWsdl(url, method, parameters, async, callback);
}
```

I tried it this way: `/// <reference path="soapclient.js" />` but it doesn't work.

Please help me!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build a definition for the external JavaScript. The best way to start with this is to look at your usage. For example, I have taken the "Hello World" example from the documentation:

```
function HelloWorld() {
    var url = 'http://localhost/';
    var pl = new SOAPClientParameters();
    SOAPClient.invoke(url, "HelloWorld", pl, true, HelloWorld_callBack);
}

function HelloWorld_callBack(r) {
    alert(r);
}
```

In order to get auto-completion and type checking for the features used, you would need to put the following code inside a file named `SoapClient.d.ts`.

```
declare class SOAPClientParameters {
}

interface SOAPClient {
    invoke(url: string, method: string, parameters: SOAPClientParameters, async: boolean, callback?: (response: any) => any);
}

declare var SOAPClient: SOAPClient;
```

In Visual Studio, this will give you the auto-completion and type checking. In some IDEs you need to add a reference comment to the TypeScript file that calls `SOAPClient`:

```
///<reference path="SoapClient.d.ts"/>
```

You still need to remember to add the actual SOAPClient JavaScript file to your page so it is available at runtime.

There are full instructions on creating your own type definitions here: [Complex Type Definitions Made Easy](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201301/Blog/Complex-TypeScript-Definitions-Made-Easy/).

Comment: So I have to do this by myself right? This is pretty much work is it?

Comment: This works for the basic case. I'm happy to help extend it - or you can carry on the idea. If it gets to "fully fledged" state it may be worth contributing to Definitely Typed :)

Comment: Sorry I don't think I get this right. You mean I should work this js file over to a d.ts file? And when it's ready post it to Definitely Typed?

Comment: No - to start with, just add the `SoapClient.d.ts` file to your project with the code I put above. Then see whether it does everything you need - that is the immediate need; to get your project running :)

Comment: Now I added the .d.ts file with the code but it doesn't call any methods from my .js file. I put alerts in them but they never show up. I also need two methods in SOAPClientParameters. Can I just put them in the class decleration? I really appriciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you definitely have the soapclient.js script tag before your  own script tag. You can add those methods to the class declaration.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare var SOAPClient: any;
```

Should get you started :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Is this enough to reference the other file or do miss anything? I can't call any methods of SOAPClient (it's not showing up on autocompletion; e.g. SOAPClient.invoke();)

Comment: For autocompletion you will need to expand it e.g take a look at other definition files on Definitely Typed

Comment: What do you mean by "expand"? Nothing on Definitely Typed for a SOAPService :(